# Unable to receive channel message without mentioning MS Teams bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-messages-with-rsc) where I added the webApplicationInfo inside manifest.json to include RSC permissions. However, I still do not receive any message activity when the bot is not mentioned in the message.

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "<i have updated app id here>",
    "resource": "https://AnyString",
    "applicationPermissions": [
      "ChannelMessage.Read.Group"
    ]
  }
```

Below is my code to echo the message:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}"), cancellationToken);
        }
```

I have checked against permissionGrant restful API ([https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/permissionGrants](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroupid%7D/permissionGrants)) and it includes "ChannelMessage.Read.Group"

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#permissionGrants",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "<id ....>",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "clientId": "<client id ...>",
            "clientAppId": "<client app id ...>",
            "resourceAppId": "<resource app id ...>",
            "permissionType": "Application",
            "permission": "ChannelMessage.Read.Group"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/15521388/120338806-25305f00-c327-11eb-9a20-ff1136d9c42a.png) to screenshot of the current situation (bot still only receives the message when bot is @mentioned.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is feature is in developer preview and It must be working with above changes in manifest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-messages-with-rsc. I tried the same and it is working fine: https://youtu.be/XUUPPDDWDtM

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru thanks for sharing! I realised I missed out switching to the developer preview mode in MS Teams. Its working now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In teams channel to send messages to bot you need to @mention the Botname. It is by design.

Answer (score 0):

now you can the RSC permissions that allows the bot to read messages without beign mentioned, check this URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-messages-with-rsc?tabs=channel%2Cdotnet#code-sample